# Adding a link to the django admin panel

Tags: python, django

I have a page and I need to go to it from the admin panel. How can I specify a link in the admin panel? Maybe you can somehow add a link to the page in the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's admin site provides a [`admin/base_site.html`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html) override point for exactly this purpose, and in fact the [documentation for overriding templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/overriding-templates/#extending-an-overridden-template) talks about that template.

Make a copy of `admin/base_site.html` somewhere in your override hierarchy (see the linked documentation above) and modify the `{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}` block to add the link you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to add a help or documentation page, you don't even need to override a template. Naming a view as `django-admindocs-docroot` will automatically add a "Documentation" link to the admin interface.

For example, add this to your urls.py:

```
    path('help/', login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='help.html')),
         name="django-admindocs-docroot"),
```